# e-mail client for iOS reading .eml attachments

Tags: ios, email-client

I'm looking for a mail client for iOS (with push IMAP and Hotmail support) that can read .eml attachments.

Actually tried Outlook, Gmail, MyMail, Cloudmail, Spark, Yahoo Mail, Cannonball, Zoho Mail, Mailburn and no one allowed opening .eml files.

Comment: Does it just need to run on the latest version of iOS, or do you need it to run on an earlier (< 9) version?

Comment: last version is enough